# Pickling Enum class

Tags: python

Im running through the documentation on enumerations. However, i dont understand what the magic qaulname refers to? It seems the location of the class where the enum can be found. Am i correct o assume that the following below would be used as part of a class attribute?

**Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ANT BEE CAT DOG', qualname='SomeData.Animal')**

Something similar to the below effect? To be honest, the documentation is poorly written.

```
class SomeData:
      Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ANT BEE CAT DOG', qualname='SomeData.Animal')
```

> Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ANT BEE CAT DOG', module=**name**) Warning If
> module is not supplied, and Enum cannot determine what it is, the new
> Enum members will not be unpicklable; to keep errors closer to the
> source, pickling will be disabled. The new pickle protocol 4 also, in
> some circumstances, relies on **qualname** being set to the location
> where pickle will be able to find the class. For example, if the class
> was made available in class SomeData in the global scope:
>
> Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ANT BEE CAT DOG', qualname='SomeData.Animal')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct.

In order to unpickle an object, you need two pieces of information. The first is what module to load to have the right information.  The second is what it is named in that module.

The source code is at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/enum.py. It makes a good faith attempt to discover the module from the calling code as follows:

```
    # TODO: replace the frame hack if a blessed way to know the calling
    # module is ever developed
    if module is None:
        try:
            module = sys._getframe(2).f_globals['__name__']
        except (AttributeError, ValueError, KeyError):
            pass
```

If you believe that will be wrong, you can pass in an explicit `module` argument.  (Rarely needed.)

The other piece is information is available in `obj.__qualname__` which defaults to `obj.__name__` which is the classname.  Normally this is correct and you need to do nothing.

But look at your example:

```
class SomeData:
    Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ANT BEE CAT DOG', qualname='SomeData.Animal')
```

The class name is `Animal` so `obj.__name__` will be `Animal`.  But it it is actually available as `SomeData.Animal`.  `Enum` doesn't have a way to figure that out unless you initialize the class with `qualname=...` to tell it that.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation explains the purpose of the argument:

> The new pickle protocol 4 also, in some circumstances, relies on **qualname** being set to the location where pickle will be able to find the class.

It also gives an example:

> For example, if the class was made available in class SomeData in the global scope:
>
> Animal = Enum('Animal', 'ANT BEE CAT DOG', qualname='SomeData.Animal')

How is that unclear?

Comment: Please avoid being patronizing. There's always one